# python requests issues with non ascii file names

Tags: python, encoding, decode, python-requests, mailgun

I'm using python requests to post a request.
when the attachment parameter has some non ascii characters an exception is raised, in other occasions where only ascii data exists, everything is fine.

[you can see the exception here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuZ2m.jpg)

```
response = requests.post(url="https://api.mailgun.net/v2/%s/messages" % utils.config.mailDomain,
                auth=("api", utils.config.mailApiKey),
                data={
                        "from" : me,
                        "to" : recepients,
                        "subject" : subject,
                        "html" if html else "text" : message
                    },

                files= [('attachment', codecs.open(f.decode('utf8'))) for f in attachments] if attachments and len(attachments) else []                                
                )
```

***EDITS:***
After decoding the file name with utf8, I don't get an exception however the file is not attached.
I debugged requests with attaching a file with only ascii characters in its name, and the request headers requests build is:

```
{'Content-Type': None, 'Content-Location': None, 'Content-Disposition': u'form-data; name="attachment"; filename="Hello.docx"'}
```

This succeeds, I'm getting the mail with the attachments.

However, when using a file with Hebrew characters, the request's header is:

```
{'Content-Type': None, 'Content-Location': None, 'Content-Disposition': 'form-data; name="attachment"; filename*=utf-8\'\'%D7%91%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%94.doc'}
```

I get the mail but without the file attached to it. Any ideas?

Comment: Show us the error trace. The picture you provide shows, there is some attempt to create a header with unexpected characters. But this can be a case for multiple values you have in your code and stacktrace would tell us more. Ideally you should provide short piece of code, which runs and show the problem. Currently it is not possible to reproduce much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the filename contains non-ascii, requests library encodes it following standard [RFC 2231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2231). The format is as what you saw: `filename*=utf-8''......`. Seems the MailGun doesn't support this standard, as a result, non-ascii filenames got lost. You may contact MailGun to confirm what format they expect for unicode filenames.

As a not-perfect workaround, you can replace non-ascii chars as:

```
def replace_non_ascii(x): return ''.join(i if ord(i) < 128 else '_' for i in x)
```

And explicitly specify filename when calling requests as (assume `attachments` is list of unicode-based filenames):

```
files= [('attachment', (replace_non_ascii(f), codecs.open(f))) for f in attachments] ...
```

**EDITS**

If you want to customize the header format, let's assume (instead of standard RFC 2231) MailGun can accept this kind of format:

```
filename="%D7%91%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%94.doc"
```

Then you can customize filenames as:

```
import urllib
def custom_filename(x): return urllib.quote(x.encode('utf8'))

files= [('attachment', (custom_filename(f), codecs.open(f))) for f in attachments] ...
```

Depending on MailGun's response, it may be possible that you need to tweak codes of `requests` or use low level libraries (urllib2) instead. Hopefully they can support RFC 2231

Comment: I'm already doing that, the problem is that the file doesn't go through for some reason... there is no exception (see in the edits section). I will update the code in the question to avoid confusions also

Comment: Thanks, I will check with mailGun. If this is the case, how can I force requests to treat unicode file names the way mailGun states?

Comment: Thanks, will wait for mailgun's response